# Where clause and model function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my model:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current
  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def current
    true unless Time.now>self.expires_on
  end
end
```

Then I am trying this:

```
Ad.where(location: "Dispenser Show Sidebar Left", current: true)
```

Here is the error:

```
Unknown column 'ads.current' in 'where clause'
```

**How can I call current in the where clause?**

Comment: If http://stackoverflow.com/a/24945800/3034747 doesnt solve the problem. Than, why you put true on current ? 'current: true'. Is there any specific result you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your `current` method into a scope:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current
  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  scope :current, -> {
    where(['expires_on < ?', Time.now])
  }
end
```

And then chain it to the `where` conditions

```
Ad.where(location: "Dispenser Show Sidebar Left").current
```

Comment: I had to use scope :current, -> { where(['expires_on < ?', Time.now]) }

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the where method produces an SQL statement to query the database. If it's not a column in the table if can't be in  where.

However, expires_on is a column, you can query by expires_on with something like this

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

  def Ad.for_location(location)
    where(
      location: location
    ).where(
      "expires_on < ?", Time.now
    )
  end

end
```

You could also make current a class method on Ad with just the second where clause, which you can then chain with another where clause for further filtering...

```
def Ad.current
  where('expires_on < Time.now)
end

def Ad.for_location(location)
  where(location: location)
end
```

Then elsewhere you could do...

```
Ad.current.for_location("Dispenser show sidebar left")
```

or

```
Ad.current.where(user_id: 1).order('id asc')
```

The arel querying engine (rails 3 onwards) builds a query which can then have the same methods (where, order, joins) called on it to build the query up. So you can wrap part of a query up in a method and still query further.

hope this helps.